# Unable to use AWS JS SDK V3 to list all tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I am following the AWS SDK v3 for Javascript guide to display my DynamoDb table names.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

However, I am receiving the following error. Any help in understanding why I am receiving this error would be greatly appreciated! :-)

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ExclusiveStartTableName')
    at serializeAws_json1_0ListTablesInput (C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_json1_0.js:3833:19)
    at serializeAws_json1_0ListTablesCommand (C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_json1_0.js:357:27)
    at serialize (C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\commands\ListTablesCommand.js:40:72)
    at C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\serializerMiddleware.js:12:27
    at C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-endpoint\dist-cjs\endpointMiddleware.js:20:16
    at async C:\source\training\react\portfolio-app\finance_api\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist-cjs\loggerMiddleware.js:5:22
    at async listTables (file:///C:/source/training/react/portfolio-app/finance_api/src/helper/listAWSTable.js:6:21)
    at async file:///C:/source/training/react/portfolio-app/finance_api/src/helper/runAWSCommands.js:4:1
```

Here are the contents of the javascript file I am using to extract the list of tables, it's basically copied from the developer-guide.

**NB** I have substituted in my region and I have AWS credentials loaded in my VSCode.

##### listAWSTables.js

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ListTablesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

async function listTables() {

  const dbclient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "ap-southeast-2" });

  try {
    const results = await dbclient.send(new ListTablesCommand());
    results.Tables.forEach(function (item, index) {
      console.log(item.Name);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

export { listTables };
```

I call it from another file "runAWSCommands.js":

##### runAWSCommands.js

```
import { listTables } from "./listAWSTables.js"; 

await listTables();
```

At the commandline I start it off using this command:  `node runAWSCommands.js`

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK Code Examples Code library has an example in multiple languages, (including JS) for [listing tables with DynamoDB.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_dynamodb_ListTables_section.html)
There is also a [longer scenario](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_dynamodb_Scenario_GettingStartedMovies_section.html) that does include listing tables and other SDK actions.
If you'd like to explore or run in your IDE you can [download the repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples).

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ExclusiveStartTableName')
```

It is saying: "The ListTablesCommand cannot read a property from an input that is undefined"

If we look at the definition type of `ListTablesCommand`:

[image]

It expects an input value. If we look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/listtablescommand.html), we can also see an `input` variable there.

This input object can be empty, in case you don't want to pass any configuration.

Hence, you can change the line:

```js
const results = await dbclient.send(new ListTablesCommand());
```

to:

```js
const results = await dbclient.send(new ListTablesCommand({}));
```

And it should work as expected.